# Search only reads one keyword: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having an issue with my search feature of my website. It's not handling search terms with more than one word. try a live example of the search bar problem over at http://mobile.mixtapemonkey.com/

search "It's Better This Way"
as soon as you type in B I get an error. other than that it works, what do you think the issue is?

```
    if (empty($errors)) {
  $name_explode = explode(' ', $name); // explode keywords to get each individual keyword, and put into array
  $name_count = count($name_explode); // count keywords from array
  foreach($name_explode as $name_single) {
    $x++; // increment x each loop

    $keyword = "%".$name_single."%";

    $where .= '`keywords` LIKE :keyword'; // append to where clause
    if ($name_count!=$x) {
      $where .= ' AND '; // as long as keyword isn't the last, append AND.
    }
  } 

  $sql = "SELECT `name`, `thumb`, `id`, `title` FROM `mixtapes` WHERE ".$where." ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 40";

  $search = $db->prepare($sql); // perform query

  $search->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);

  $search->execute();

  $search_num_rows = $search->rowCount(); // get number of rows (results) returned
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the code I have added.the reason you got that error is due to your foreach loop. In that loop you add :keyword everytime. But that count dont match with the bindParam value count. So I changed you code and posting below

```
if (empty($errors)) {
$name_explode = explode(' ', $name); // explode keywords to get each individual keyword, and put into array
$name_count = count($name_explode); // count keywords from array
$x = 0;
foreach($name_explode as $name_single) {
$x++; // increment x each loop

$keyword[':keyword'.$x] = "%".$name_single."%";

$where .= '`keywords` LIKE :keyword'.$x; // append to where clause
if ($name_count!=$x) {
  $where .= ' OR '; // as long as keyword isn't the last, append AND.
}
} 

$sql = "SELECT `name`, `thumb`, `id`, `title` FROM `mixtapes` WHERE ".$where." ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 40";

$search = $db->prepare($sql); // perform query


$search->execute($keyword);

$search_num_rows = $search->rowCount(); //
```

Comment: I'm not getting errors but I'm also not getting any results at all now.

Comment: can you echo your $sql and see how its binded?

Comment: change your AND to OR inside for loop

Comment: just added the echo to the live demo if you want to check it out for yourself. http://mobile.mixtapemonkey.com/

Comment: that didn't help either. still 0 results.

Comment: I have changed this line 
$keyword[':keyword'.$x] = "%".$name_single."%";  . Also please print_r this value